# I want to extract/parse value from string

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
string1 = 'http://localhost/dir/file.js?ver=3.5.4'
string2 = 'OneWord 2.5.4'
```

I want to extract the end values from these strings like:

```
extracted1 = '3.5.4'
extracted2 = '2.5.4'
```

Note that these (version) number values I want to extract are not the same every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

semver = r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+'

def get_semver(string):
    return re.search(semver, string).group(0)
```

Usage:

```
>>> get_semver(string1)
'3.5.4'
>>> get_semver(string2)
'2.5.4'
```

---

If you want to only match them at the end of the strings, add a `$` to the regular expression.

Comment: Maybe add `$` to make sure it only matches at the end?

Answer (score 0):

If your string will remain same,means URL,doesnot matter if vesion number will be different you can use the following code.
Actually you need to be more clear what you want actually:

```
string1 = 'http://localhost/dir/file.js?ver=3.5.4'
string2 = 'OneWord 2.5.4'
extracted1 = string1.split("=")[1]
extracted2= string2.split(" ")[1]
```